# Inserting from a small range of values into a large results table

Tags: mysql

I have a large number of results that I would like to split between 3 users to check.

```
select data from t1
```

This is the result I am expecting:

```
user    data
1       apples
2       oranges
3       bananas
1       passion fruit
2       pineapples
3       peaches
1       melon
2       plums
3       pears
```

And so on. In other words, the data in the second column is different, but the user column 'cycles' between 1-3.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SET @user = 0;
SeLect @user := CASE WHEN @user = 3 THEN 1 ELSE @user+1 END as user,
data FROM Table1
```

Comment: Hmmm... can't see how to mark it as correct? Perhaps I don't have the correct priviliges.